# How to improve the quality (smoothness) of lines in contourplots Matlab's

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contour

How the line smoothness in a contour plot can be improved for publications? For instance, the dotted lines look really bad, the continuous lines look as if their thickness varies. See below

Here's part of the code:

```
Vals = [0:5:200]; contourf(X,Y,W,Vals,'EdgeColor','k','LineWidth',1.2,'LineStyle',':');axis square;grid;hold on
Vals = [10:10:200]; contour(X,Y,W,Vals,'EdgeColor','k','LineWidth',1.2);
Vals = [20 : 20 : 200]; [C,h] = contour(X,Y,W,Vals,'Color','k','LineWidth',1.8);
clabel(C,h,'FontName','Palatino Linotype','FontAngle','italic','Fontsize',9,'Color','w')

print -djpeg -r300 filename
```

Thanks!

[image]

Saved as png doesn't help much... check the lines :/ See below:

[image]

Check the dotted lines now...

[image]

Here's saving as eps (-r1200)... it looks better

[image]

Comment: Could you show how you made the image? Preferably with a minimal working example. In general increasing the size of the image should help.

Comment: Ideally you could produce some input parameters as well. But besides that, perhaps you can try the various file types like .png under file>save as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** I see your example code now. Did you try changing `-r300` to some really high value? More pixels per inch should make everything look smoother. For publication, crank it up really high, like `-r1200`.

**Original:**
One thing you can try is exporting the plot in some format that supports vector graphics. Matlab supports both PDF and EMF, so try one of those. Export using the [`saveas`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html) command or from the figure's "File -> Save as" menu item. After that, open or import the image file in some other application and hopefully it will look better.

Please add a new screenshot if you get a nicer image!

Comment: That did the trick...!! check however the dotted line. They look awful.. any ideas how to improve this?

Comment: @OliverAmundsen I don't know what to do about the dotted lines. If you can't fix it, can you switch to a different line style?

Comment: I might have to post a new question to address that one, because it's a very common and annoying problem in Matlab graphs, thanks!

Comment: @OliverAmundsen It's probably worth trying some vector graphics format, like EPS or PDF, instead of JPEG. The dotted lines may work doing it that way.

Answer (score 4):

Exporting as vector graphics will definitely improve the image over what you see on your screen; I use LaTeX for publications and you can either export to `eps` for postscript output, and use `epstopdf` for PDF output, and embed these directly in your document; that would be the best solution.

Additionally, there are also a bunch of general utilities for making your plots look better for camera-ready publications, the most notable that comes to mind is exportfig, which has a load of features to help even with pixel graphics. These go above and beyond just generating smoother-looking images.

**http://www.mathworks.us/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig**

(copied from that page):

This function saves a figure or single axes to one or more vector and/or bitmap file formats, and/or outputs a rasterized version to the workspace, with the following properties:

- Figure/axes reproduced as it appears on screen
- Cropped borders (optional)
- Embedded fonts (pdf only)
- Improved line and grid line styles
- Anti-aliased graphics (bitmap formats)
- Render images at native resolution (optional for bitmap formats)
- Transparent background supported (pdf, eps, png)
- Semi-transparent patch objects supported (png only)
- RGB, CMYK or grayscale output (CMYK only with pdf, eps, tiff)
- Variable image compression, including lossless (pdf, eps, jpg)
- Optionally append to file (pdf, tiff)
- Vector formats: pdf, eps
- Bitmap formats: png, tiff, jpg, bmp, export to workspace

This function is especially suited to exporting figures for use in publications and presentations, because of the high quality and portability of media produced.